# Line break with operators clang format

Tags: c++, clang-format

My codebase consists of the both the styles below. I want to retain both styles because that means fewer code changes that need to be made.

Style 1

```
if (!fun1(param)
    && fun2((type*)f, param) == FALSE)
    continue;
```

Style 2

```
if ((v0 == n0 || v0 == n1 || v0 == n2) &&
    (v1 == n0 || v1 == n1 || v1 == n2))
{
    return out;
}
```

Clang-format has a BreakBeforeBinaryOperators that introduces line breaks after operators. My problem is that both styles cannot be simultaneously supported, i.e., if I use BreakBeforeBinaryOperators = None
Style 1 becomes

```
if (!fun1(param) && fun2((type*)f, param) == FALSE)
    continue;
```

Style 2 is retained.

With BreakBeforeBinaryOperators = NonAssignment or BreakBeforeBinaryOperators = All,
Style 1 is retained
Style 2 becomes

```
if ((v0 == n0 || v0 == n1 || v0 == n2) && (v1 == n0 || v1 == n1 || v1 == n2))
{
    return out;
}
```

This result is neither here nor there. Further, it would be fine if both Style 1 and Style 2 become consistent after the change but that does not happen either. What should I change?

I'm on clang format 16. I use a `ColumnLimit : 0`. `AlignOperands: Align`
Please let me know in case there are any other relevant config params to mention in the post.

Comment: This goes pretty much directly against the design of tools like `clang-format`: they parse code (albeit in a fashion that retains certain comments and whitespace) and then produce _one_ output according to the configuration that deliberately ignores existing formatting.  If you gave it a conditional that didn’t match either of your preferred styles, how would it pick which style to apply?

Comment: Fair enough. However, I should at least get a single consistent style using the settings which I am not. Note that in my example I have 2 different code styles but clang format only affects one of them and certainly does not give a consistent output.

Comment: That’s a separate question—how to get the tool to use _one_ of your desired formats precisely.  Of course, that might lie outside the space of possible configurations as well, but that’s less likely (for “plausible” preferences).

Comment: Well, I've mentioned it in my question. If you know the answer, it would be nice if you could help instead of making oblique statements on plausible circumstances